# Can I join remote and local repository

Tags: git

I have some repo (R#1) at my PC1 and empty remote repo (R#2). I need share this, but my PC1 haven`t internet connection.  My desicion is copy my local repo to other PC2, that have internet connection. I had created repo in PC2 and added remote R#2 and push. Then I changed R#1, but when I copied repo to PC2, remote link had disappeared. How can I push data to remote repo with existing change, that had been commited?

Comment: I am not sure if that works, but did you copy the *.git* folder? This is the one who stores the URL.

Answer (score 0):

You can add the remote as a new remote.

(If your repository wasn't initialized, run `git init`)

```
git remote add <name of remote> <URL of remote>
```

Example:

```
git remote add origin example.git
```

You can do that and then push it from your computer that has internet.

Following the example:

```
git push origin master
```

This would send the local branch 'master' to example.git's 'master'.

Comment: But I have commit on my no internet PC. I do what you told and 'git status' asked me, that there are no commits.

Comment: Did you try checking `git log`? You can also commit in the other PC